# Linux VPN server without port forwarding

Tags: ssh, linux, server, vpn, port-forwarding

I want to make a VPN server on my raspberry PI. I know it's pretty much simple task but my router does not support port forwarding. So is there any other way to do that?

Comment: One possibility is to use a reverse tunnel but for this you need a relay server (a RasPi is enough) on the internet. You wll then connect to the relay server instead to your router. Could this be a solution for you?

Comment: @Ingo, I can't remember the name of an online service capable to provide relay ,can you put example please ?

Comment: More or less any VPS could be used as a relay. Digital Ocean, for example.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used a third party service yet so I cannot help with it.

Comment: @Ingo, No problem thanks anyway.

Comment: I have found this [video on youtube from hack5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7qr0laM8kA) , Digital Ocean is use for the example ...
I think it's the same goal, no?